# How likely is it for a small Li-ion battery to catch fire on it's own?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

Today, I have lost a very small e-cigarette with 260mAh battery probably in an area with a lot of chaff and other flamable stuff,

I'm really scared, tried searching everywhere but didn't find it!

How likely is it, for this device to catch fire on it's own? it had like 60% charge left I believe.

Here is an screenshot of the battery I found on youtube:
[image]

Any help/comment is appreciated.

Comment: Just on its own? Not really high unless something mechanically damages or corrodes the the device or it overheats somehow...both of which which could conceivably happen if it's buried in a bunch of chaff.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you very much for the comment, what about aging, is it likely to catch fire in a few years on it's own? also is it more likely going to be a flame, or just smoke?

Comment: If it's in a temperature controlled environment and not subject to corrosion or mechanical damage,  not likely due to aging. It's more likely to smoke but in a bunch of chaff smoking won't really matter since being buried in chaff cause the heat to ignite something. 50-60% charger is what you're normally supposed to store batteries at anyways and they do lose their charge over time and become less dangerous as they do but for them to reach zero could take decades.

Comment: Did you lose it outdoors where it will eventually be rained on?  There is a good chance for moisture to short it out and deplete it when everything around is moist and harder to burn.  If the battery gets punctured while it still holds a charge, that's probably your greatest danger, although unlikely.

Comment: @KH Yes it is outside, and it gets rainy too, and in the winter 10-20 cm of snow can hit the ground, the area is mostly soil, with trees and some dry branches, but 2 large packs of chaff/straw are around too.

Do you think after the winter we can assume it's safe?

Comment: I don't know about assuming it's safe, but the device doesn't appear to have a heating element capable of acting as an ignition source, so if it failed on it would likely harmlessly deplete the battery, it appears to have a metal case so it's unlikely to be punctured, and it will be somewhat regularly exposed to moisture so it will likely deteriorate and/or deplete the battery over time.  That said, maybe it deteriorates in such a way as to dead short the remaining battery charge somehow on a dry day.  Nothing is impossible.

Comment: @KH @ DKNguyen Thank you both very much for the time you put into the comments, it was really helpful to me.

Comment: @DKNguyen By the way, I just realized the battery is Li-Poli rather than Li-Ion, does that make a difference in my situation?

Comment: I had assumed you meant LiPo